# Travis Or Jenkins for local git repo?

Tags: git, continuous-integration

We have a local git repository created at institute level.

Travis is a hosted CI tool and Jenkins has to be set up locally.

As the projects are confidential, is Travis safe for such local private repositories or Jenkins is the better option?

What are other CI options for private git repositories?

Comment: Setup and use Jenkins. Since you won't have to worry about Travis' cost (for private repos). 
Travis will take care of the security of your project, because you'll be paying them since they will be under legal obligation. You'll have to read their privacy policy, ToS, etc.

Comment: After more search I think jenkins will be more suaitable in this case as u suggested.Thanks for help.